# I cannot see my collections in mongo db atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I cannot see my collection in mongo db

here is my cmd screenshot
[cmd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7s4y.png)

this my screenshot of my mondo db

[mongo db screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqyz8.png)

Comment: You shouldn't put those private keys in the repo and post them here.

Comment: Is there a document in the collection yet? The server will make the collection once there is the first doc.

Comment: which doc are you talking about